# How to subtract time (obtained in hour, minute and second) in string from other similar time stored in array to use it as the condition for loop in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime

I obtain data from a text file, do some json parsing and extract the time in the format of

```
"Fri Oct 30 15:32:50 +0000 2015"
```

which I store as an array of string. Then I split string as hour, minute and second as

```
"15:32:50".
```

I have number of such rows and I need to track the event within 30 seconds of time. I read each line using stream reader. How do I form a condition for loop subtracting each time from the first one so that the loop continues until there is 30 seconds of interval.This is what I have done.

```
StreamReader streamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText("D:\\file.txt");
        string lineContent = streamReader.ReadLine();
        int count = 0;
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\ft1.txt"))
        {
            do
            {
                if (lineContent != null)
                {
                    string a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(lineContent).ToString();
                    string b = "[" + a + "]";
                    List<TweetModel> deserializedUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TweetModel>>(b);
                    var CreatedAt = deserializedUsers.Select(user => user.created_at).ToList();
                    string[] TimeSplit = CreatedAt[0].Split(null);
                    string hourMinSec = TimeSplit[3]; 

                }
                lineContent = streamReader.ReadLine();

            }
            while (streamReader.Peek() != -1);

            streamReader.Close();

        }
```

This is my tweet model.

```
 public class TweetModel
{
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

This is one line from file.txt.

```
{"created_at":"Thu Oct 29 17:51:50 +0000 2015","id":659789756637822976,"id_str":"6597897566378229","text":"@Kusum told me to get up"}
```

I am confused how to make the first line containing time as static and then subtracting time stored as string in array from every row and continue doing this until the interval is 30 seconds to track certain events within the time. Please help.

Comment: Could you share your `TweetModel` with us? And maybe one or more lines from `file.txt`? That might shed some light on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @venerik please check I have updated the question adding them.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure about what you are trying to achieve but here's some code that makes it much easier to retrieve the date from the tweet:

```
class TwitterDateConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public TwitterDateConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
    }
}

public class TweetModel
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TwitterDateConverter))]
    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Using this code `TweetModel.CreatedAt` is a normal DateTime object instead of a clumsy string.

Hope it helps.

**Update**

Added a slimmed down solution to your question (I guess).

```
using (var streamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText("D:\\file.txt"))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\ft1.txt"))
    {
        DateTime? startTime = null;
        while(streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            var tweet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TweetModel>(line);
            var createdAt = tweet.CreatedAt;

            // set the start time when it has not been set yet
            startTime = startTime ?? createdAt;

            // leave the while loop when createdAt is later than startTime plus 30 seconds
            if (createdAt > (startTime.Value + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
            {
                break;
            }

            // do something useful with the tweet
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this converter, I didn't know it can be converted. But still I am wondering as I read one line at a time using Stream Reader, the first time I encounter a created_at, I will subtract all other incoming created_at from the first one until I dont get the interval as 30 in seconds. How would I keep the first created_at value as static so that I can use it for rest iterations?